# I'm trying to upload image with Jquery and ajax function using codeigniter framework. i can see the error blow:

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice Message:
>
> Undefined index: uploadimg
>
> Filename: models/upload_model.php
>
> Line Number: 26

My code:

**Controller**

```
public function do_upload(){
    $this->upload->do_upload();
    if($this->upload_model->Doupload()){
        echo 1;
    }else{
        echo 0;
    }
}
 private function set_config_option(){
    $config =array(
        'allowed_type' => 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|doc|xml|zip|rar',
        'file_size'  => '100',
        'max_width'  => '1024',
        'overwrite'  => TRUE,
        'max_height' => '768',
    );
    return $config;
}
```

**Model**

```
 private function set_config_option(){
    $config =array(
        'allowed_type' => 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|doc|xml|zip|rar',
        'file_size'  => '2048000',
        'max_width'  => '1024',
        'overwrite'  => TRUE,
        'max_height' => '768'
    );
    return $config;
}

public function Doupload(){         
    $target_path = 'uploads/';
    $target_file = $target_path. basename($_FILES['uploadimg']['name']);
    $base_url = base_url();
    $img_title = $this->input->post('imgname');

    $this->upload->initialize('upload', $this->set_config_option());
  //  $img = $this->upload->do_upload();    
   }
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

The model isn't receiving the $_FILES object. Why you separate the upload proccess in 2 files (model & controller?, you store something in the database?). In the codeiniter documentation: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html is all in the same file (controller).

Try following the example or try to add in the controller:

```
$this->upload_model->Doupload($_FILES);
```

and in the model:

```
public function Doupload($file){
    $target_path = 'uploads/';
    $target_file = $target_path. basename($file['uploadimg']['name']);
```

I guess you load the library with: `$this->load->library('upload');` or by autoload config class. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your ajax request and if that helps :) 
And i assume you using form/multipart

```
 xhr: function() {
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        return myXhr;
},
```